# Angular Architecture - Importing Third Party libraries for consuming it into Feature modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ag-grid

I am creating a fresh angular application which consist of multiple feature modules.
I am installing Material Design in that.
I want to know what should be the right way to import modules from Material Design into my feature modules.

Eg.
1. Create a seperate module "MaterialModule" and import it into all feature modules.

2. Import MaterialModule into ShareModule or what.

I also want to play with Ag-Grid. Wanted to know where should I import it.
 1. AppModule
 2. Individual Feature Module

My aim is achieve speed optimization, when the application grows.

Comment: Hi, I see an accepted answer. But I also answered the same first. May I know why is not accepted. Just wanted to know the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that most of the people create a separate module say `material.module.ts` and include all the Mat Modules in this file and import this Module in the module that they need.

This way, the code looks neater but is not effective in terms of size of the app

I prefer to import only the Mat modules that I need for a particular module.

Answer (score 0):

Import whatever Material module you need in each feature module.

Otherwise you will inevitably end importing modules you don't need.